# Should I check variables length every time?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm storing user data in a mysql database, and everytime user data gets **INSERTED**, or **EDITED**, then I do check the length of the variable

```
if (strlen($firstName) > 20) {
  exit("Too long name!");
}
// + INSERT INTO THE DATABASE ...
```

But should I check the length if I just **SELECT** from the database?

Like:

```
if (strlen($firstName) > 20) {
  exit();
}
// + SELECT FROM THE DATABASE ...
```

I'm just wondering, because I don't want people to be able to slow down the server where my database is..

Is it possible to slow down databases if user enters a really long (1000000 character or more) string as an input value?

Comment: If anything, the round trip to the database is definitely worth saving.

Comment: I agree with @ishegg. if it doesn't meet your criteria, avoid the query altogether. The database is indexed so it will quickly know that there are no matches to a long (undesired) string. It's just the bandwidth you're taking to send a several Kb long char up to the server for the query, which again, you should avoid.

Answer (score -1):

If the string is only ever stored at less than 20 characters, I do not see how it could ever select anything over 20 characters, so the second (select) check is redundant

Comment: If you read it again, its before select not after. also answer the last bit.

Comment: I have read it again. How do you SELECT something from a database if it's not in there? He stores usernames only under 20 characters.

Comment: Just because its not there does not mean the SELECT wont happen with 1000000 char query, which is what the OP is asking. *Is it possible to slow down databases if user enters a really long (1000000 character or more) string as an input value?*

Comment: Perhaps mention max post size.

Comment: If that's what OP means then he should definitely use a different variable in the second example, what are we supposed to be mind-readers?